# syntax error can't see the were its going wrong

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok so im doing a mysql select and if there is no result then we will insert it if there is a result we update it but im getting the 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Here is my full code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from new_battles WHERE player1='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0)
{# If row already exists, then update it.

$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE new_battles SET player1 = '"$_SESSION['username']"' AND player2 = '"$_SESSION['vsuser']"' 
AND onpokemonplayer1 = '1'  AND onpokemonplayer2 = '1'  WHERE player1 = '"$_SESSION['username']"' ")
or die(mysql_error());
}
else
{# If row doesn't exist, then insert row.
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO new_battles (player1, player2,onpokemonplayer1,onpokemonplayer2) VALUES('"$_SESSION['username']"', '"$_SESSION['vsuser']"' , '1', '1')")
or die(mysql_error());
}
```

It says the error is on the mysql update bit... Maybe im using to many and's ???

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `.` to concatenate your variable in the query:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE new_battles
            SET player1 = '".$_SESSION['username']."',
            player2 = '".$_SESSION['vsuser']."',
            onpokemonplayer1 = '1',
            onpokemonplayer2 = '1'
            WHERE player1 = '".$_SESSION['username']."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

EDIT: as asked in the comments, you UPDATE query was wrong, to update multiple fields you need to separate them with commas and not AND.

Comment: The update does not update does not work it updates the table with a 0

Comment: Then your update query is wrong, that was not really your original question. I updated the answer, you need to separate column to update with commas, not AND

Answer (score 1):

Every syntax error had to deal with [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from new_battles WHERE player1='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0){# If row already exists, then update it.

    $result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE new_battles SET player1 = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND player2 = '".$_SESSION['vsuser']."' 
    AND onpokemonplayer1 = '1'  AND onpokemonplayer2 = '1'  WHERE player1 = '".$_SESSION['username']."' ")
    or die(mysql_error());
}else{# If row doesnt exist, then insert row.
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO new_battles (player1, player2,onpokemonplayer1,onpokemonplayer2) VALUES('".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$_SESSION['vsuser']."' , '1', '1')") or die(mysql_error());
}?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the functionality, I'm only speaking of the syntax errors